# Outlook for Mac 16.71 - Missing Clear conversations feature

Tags: mail.app, email, messages, ms-office

I recently switched from HP Zbook running Windows 10 with Outlook 2016 to Apple Macbook Pro (M1 pro) running Ventura with Outlook 2016. My work email account is an office 365 account.

There was a nifty little feature in Outlook for windows where I can clean up redundant messages on a mail thread. It is as explained here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conversation-clean-up-to-delete-redundant-messages-70179d54-fa57-48ce-95fd-416d72e5ccd4

This feature seems to be missing in my Outlook for macOS. I can only arrange emails by Conversations, but unable to delete the redundant messages as there is no option provided. Is this known limitation? I checked Apple's mail app documentation, and this also does not have the feature to clear redundant messages in a conversation.

I would be grateful for

1. An answer if this is indeed a limitation in Outlook for macOS
2. An alternative app suggestion where this feature is available.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

So based on https://www.groovypost.com/howto/quickly-clean-up-your-microsoft-outlook-inbox/ this is apparently not possible in macOS. That answers #1 of my question.